# Second http request fails with HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT, but when run first is ok?

Tags: node.js

Having a very annoying problem with Node.js. I'm trying to run a script that performs 2 simple http requests, the second using some data retrieved in the first one.

The problem is I'm getting this error on the second request:

> { [Error: Parse Error] bytesParsed: 0, code: 'HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT' }
>   { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }

I've looked at potential causes for this error, and it primarily seems to be incorrectly formatted responses from the server. Things is, the code also outputs the path that is being requested in the second request, and when I copy that exact path into the first request and run it again, there is no error and it gives the output expected.

Code is below, I've added in a timeout between first and second requests to make sure it's not that the server just isn't ready for the second request yet. What am I doing wrong?

```
firstRequest();


function firstRequest() {

    var http = require('http');

    var strPath = '/lookup?username=XXXXXXXX&password=XXXXXXXX&destination=447412315463';
    //strPath = '/report?batchid=2402161244556393';


    console.log('Path 1: '+strPath);

    var options = {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: '8080',
      path: strPath
    }; 


    callback = function(response) {

        var str = '';

        //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log(chunk);
            str += chunk;
        });

        //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
        response.on('end', function () {

            console.log(str);
            setTimeout(function() {
              secondRequest(str);
            }, 10000);

        });


    }

    http.request(options, callback).end();

}

function secondRequest(str) {


    var http = require('http');


    var arrParts = str.split(" ");
    var strPath = '/report?batchid='+arrParts[1];


    console.log('Path 2: '+strPath);

    var options = {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: '8080',
      path: strPath
    }; 

    callback = function(response) {

        var str = '';

        //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {

            console.log(chunk);

            str += chunk;
        });

        //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
        response.on('end', function () {

            console.log(str);

        });


    }

    http.request(options, callback).end();

}


process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log(err);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, found it, there must have been a \n on the end of the batchid I was using in the second path, .trim when putting the path together and was fine